# (AS3) Does setting variables to private help garbage collection?

Tags: actionscript-3, memory, memory-management, actionscript, garbage-collection

Novice programmer here.

I'm currently coding a simple game with the title screen and the main game loop in separate "keyframes" (this is in CS6). Once I transition from the title screen to the game keyframe I'm concerned that the buttons/movieclips/variables are going to stick around and waste memory + clutter the screen.

If I have the variables/functions set to "private" will that help the garbage collector take care of them? How should I go about "clearing the screen" and making sure I'm not being wasteful/leaking memory?

None of the tutorials or books I've been reading to learn AS3 have really covered this topic, if there are any good guides or obvious tips I've missed as far as memory management best practice goes in AS3 I'm interested in seeing them. The only thing I've learned so far is that I should manually set all my event listeners to weak reference.

Bonus question: I'm using a full-screen bitmap and blitting things onto it for my display. If I am blitting dozens of objects onto the screen per frame I don't need to worry about the blitted "sprites" that are being "covered up," do I? I'm hoping that the bitmap is one pixel thick and not just stacking things on top of each other.

Comment: If you are using the timeline in CS6 to write your code, you likely can't use access modifiers anyway. They are only available if using custom classes and most Timeline-based code does not use custom classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, the only way you will have total control over your resources is if you leave the timeline for what it was intended for, creating and exporting assets in to swc or swf format, which you can embed the former and either embed or load the latter.

What you should be doing is learning how to develop in an Object Oriented manner, starting with a Document class (as you're using CS6) and then building your game using a series of classes which have defined tasks. Using classes promotes re-usability throughout your game. Depending on the complexity, I would consider a framework like PureMVC or Robot legs.

Garbage collection in flash is mark and sweep, which means you have to de-reference all your objects, which usually starts with removing associated listeners, timers and any further references to them, eg. clearing from arrays or objects hashes. Finally you would set the object in question to null which makes it 'elligible' for garbage collection but does not actually guarantee it. Flash will come and clean up as it sees fit.

Personally if you could get hold of Flash Builder, this has a fantastic memory management profiling tool, when you are developing using OOP mentioned above, you can use this tool to see all the instances that exist in your game. Now the good part here is you can do a memory snapshots in time, and compare them to see which objects linger around and are causing memory leaks. There is a garbage collection button which you should invoke between capturing snapshots, this is only available as you are developing, though using Adobe AIR you can force gc calls manually.

Regarding your bonus question, im not sure how you are doing this blitting, if you are adding objects to the stage this is increasing memory, you cannot avoid this. What you describe as 1px thick is what flash renders, you can see what is being redrawn by right clicking on the stage and selecting the redraw regions option, to see a red box showing what flash has to redraw, it will only redraw what it needs to, this is useful to check if your frame rate suffers.

So to summarize:

Consider using Flash CS6 for creating assets.

Learn about Object Oriented programming in Actionscript 3.

Consider developing in Flash Builder (or free Flash Develop).

OOP will help with organisation and de-referencing objects for garbage collection.

I hope this helps and good luck with your game.